# `wsl env` gives different result to `wsl` followed by `env`

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Inside WSL (i.e. by opening a cmd and then running `wsl`, or just running `wsl` straight from the start menu) I have this line at the end of `~/.bashrc`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

While still inside WSL, if I do `env` I see the following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

All is good. However if I `exit` from WSL back to the cmd prompt, and then do `wsl env` I see this:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I'm primarily a Windows person and I don't know enough of what's going on to solve this. How can I have `wsl env` give the same result for the `LANG` variable as doing `wsl` followed by `env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clonkex, this comes down to the "bash" shell invocation. When you just run "wsl" you run bash in an interactive mode. However when you run "wsl " you're running in a non-interactive mode.

The [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) describes how different forms of invocation will run different startup scripts (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, etc).

Under a UNIX/Linux environment, you can usually force bash to run in interactive mode by specifying "-i" when executing it. But wsl doesn't seem to want to allow that.

If you want to set an environment variable even when in non-interactive mode, can add commands to do this into /etc/profile, or (preferably) create a new file in /etc/profile.d/ and add the commands there. This file will be run regardless of whether you run wsl with arguments or not.

Comment: While this answer is somewhat helpful in that it mentions there's an interactive and non-interactive mode to bash, it doesn't really give a solution. For instance, the bash man page is literally >40000 words long. That's insane. I'm never going to find the info I need in that, and man pages are notoriously not noob-friendly. You mention that I can add commands to have env vars appear in non-interactive mode, but you don't say what those commands are. Could you please elaborate? You also say _"create a new file in /etc/profile.d/"_, but what new file?

Comment: Accepting since this is technically correct, since my goal was actually to do `wsl ssh 192.168.x.x "perl -e exit"` without Perl complaining, and I realised I can add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in `~./bashrc` on the remote machine to fix the problem.

Comment: Specifying "my goal [is] ... to do [yada]" is probably a good thing to do in your question.

You could create a file /etc/profile.d/set-lang.sh containing:

    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Also, you can set an environment variable when invoking a command by just prefixing A=B. So for your requirement, something like this might help:

    wsl LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ssh 192.168.x.x

Comment: Unfortunately, the way wsl executes the bash shell in non-interactive mode causes it to bypass all of the profiles, so creating the file in profile.d doesn't help you.

The other solution, with nicer formatting:

    `wsl LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ssh 192.168.x.x`